# How to create a CodeIgniter/Tank Auth login page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

So, I downloaded Tank Auth, and put it in my CodeIgniter libraries folder... Now what? Just a basic implementation of a login page (controller + view) based on this library would be very much appreciated, to get me going in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tank auth already have a register page.
Just visit http://yoururl.com/index.php/auth/register

Look at application/controllers/auth.php file.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks a lot! Now, any idea how to plug this form into my own HTML page?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend setting the 'auth' controller as your default controller in your routes config file.  Anytime you visit your root folder and aren't logged in, you'll get the login/register form.

Including the login form should be as simple as including the view in your own view file/ or controller, depending how you like to load views...

```
$this->load->view('auth/login_form');
```

or

```
$this->load->view('auth/register_form');
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use a header/footer with the standard tank auth views. I copied the 'views/auth' folder and named it 'views/auth_content'. I then went through the views/auth files and added the following:

```
$this->load->view("tiles/header", $model);;
$this->load->view("auth_content/login_form");
$this->load->view("tiles/footer");
```

Now 'views/login_form' calls the above code which then embeds the tank auth login_form with your own custom header or footer code. It's non invasive too - just delete the new 'views/auth' folder and rename 'views/auth_content' back to 'views/auth' and you use the original tank auth views again.